# Why would we expand a numpy array along axis=0?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Can anyone explain the condition in which one would require to reshape along axis=0? Please see the example below, with a given numpy array:

```py
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

(Reshaping follows below)

```py
a1 = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
```

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

Comment: I have one experience, for example in machine learning models, the input goes as (sample_number, dim1, dim2), so for eample if you have 2000 set of (28,28) images, then actual input tessor will be (2000,28,28). When you will predict from the model with a single input the the shape of the input should be (1, 28,28)

Answer (score 1):

The expansion typically happens when we are using a function, which performs operations on an `(m, n)` array, to process a special case where `m = 1`.

If the shape of the given data is `(n,)` we have to `expand_dims` along the first axis so that the shape is `(1, n)`.

Some functions are nice enough to take special care of the `(n,)` situation. But sometimes we have to do the conversion, `(n,) → (1, n)`, ourselves.